# sum of a set of complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $X=\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ and $Y=\{y_1,\ldots,y_n\}$ be two (equal size) sets of the complex numbers. If $\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^k=\sum_{i=1}^ny_i^k$, for all $k\geq 1$, then is this true that $X=Y$? How about if $x_i$'s and $y_i$'s are roots of unity?

Comment: Asked and answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/971172/42969

Comment: @VeryForgetfulFunctor  With $\;k=2\;$ the sums are not equal.